# Powershell - replace string in file with wildcards

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have a file that includes the following text:

```
hello
hello
world
world
this is a testVersion=1.2.3.4 test test
```

I am trying to update the Version=1.2.3.4 using Powershell v2 to become Version=4.3.2.1 using -replace
The version numbers are random, so this would need to account for an unknown version number but the format will always be the same with the word Version, an equals sign, and alternating digit, period, digit, period, digit, period, digit for the version number. As you can see, there is other text to the left and the right of the Version=1.2.3.4 as well, and that needs to stay where it is without being affected. After changing the version number, i need to write these changes to a new file. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An incomplete example that should be PS 2 compatible.

```
'Version=1.2.3.4' -replace '(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)', '$4.$3.$2.$1'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris - only issue is that I need to account for an unknown version number in the event that it isnt 1.2.3.4. Any ideas?

Comment: That's what it does. 4 digits separated by a dot, reassembled in reverse using the regex groups it matched in the first place. $1 to $4 are references to match groups, not literal values.